# Why doesn't dynamic partial mocking work for JMockit's @Injectable?

Tags: unit-testing, jmockit

In the following test case where no `Expectations` have been recorded, I would expect that the dynamic partial mocking feature will be used for the fields `A` and `B` which are initialized in `UnitToTest` using `@Injectable`. But instead always the method calls are mocked. Only using an invalid filter value for static partial mocking, it is possible to call the real methods:

```
@Service
class A {
 public String doSomething() {  return "doSomething";   }
 public String doSomethingElse() {  return "doSomethingElse";   }
}

@Service
class B {
 public String doSomething() {  return "doSomething";   }
 public String doSomethingElse() {  return "doSomethingElse";   }
}

@Service
class UnitToTest {
 @Autowired B b;
 @Autowired A a;
 public B getB() {  return b;   }
 public A getA() {  return a;   }
}

public class TestClass {
 @Tested    UnitToTest unit;
 // @Mocked({ "someInvalidFilter()" })
 @Injectable    A a;
 // @Mocked({ "someInvalidFilter()" })
 @Injectable    B b;

 @Test
 public void test() {
    // actual return value is always null if no invalid static partial
    // mocking filters are specified above
    assertEquals("doSomething", unit.getA().doSomething());
    assertEquals("doSomethingElse", unit.getA().doSomethingElse());
    assertEquals("doSomething", unit.getB().doSomething());
    assertEquals("doSomethingElse", unit.getB().doSomethingElse());
 }
}
```

For me it looks like dynamic partial mocking with JMockit doesn't work for `@Injectable`s. Is that a known restriction?

Comment: There is no dynamic partial mocking going on in the example test; for that, you would need to have a "new Expectations(a, b) { ... }" expectation recording block. But then "a" and "b" should probably be real instances, not mocked ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it means that no dependency injection would be available. Instead I would have to use Deencapsulation.setField(). Is it planned to extend the Mocking framework to support partial dynamic mocking also for the `@Injectable`s? Or at least can I rely on the support of above mentioned workaround in future releases?

Comment: Partial mocking and injection of @Injectable's are two entirely different parts of the mocking API. I don't think I get what you are trying to say; it would be much easier if you could explain what it is that you are actually trying to test.

Comment: The idea is to use `@Injectable`s for `@Autowired` fields to simplify unit testing. And only if `Expectations` are recorded or a `Mockup` is used, I would expect that the existing behaviour is mocked. If none of these is used, I would rely on calls of the real methods. So calling the methods of `A` or `B` in above test case, the real methods should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Injectable`s always get injected into `@Tested` objects, assuming a matching field or constructor parameter can be found; the injection process even takes into consideration DI annotations such as `@Inject` and `@Autowired`.

However, an `@Injectable` instance is always created as an *uninitialized* (ie, with no state) and *fully mocked* instance. Partial mocking, on the other hand, is meant for *real* instances that you instantiate (and initialize) yourself in the test.

So, what you seem to be asking for is that said real instances (partially mocked or not) could be injected into `@Tested` objects. Indeed, this is not supported (except by calling `Deencapsulation.setField`), since a motivating use case was never presented by users.

That said, the example test will pass if it is changed to the following:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true) UnitToTest unit;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("doSomething", unit.getA().doSomething());
        assertEquals("doSomethingElse", unit.getA().doSomethingElse());
        assertEquals("doSomething", unit.getB().doSomething());
        assertEquals("doSomethingElse", unit.getB().doSomethingElse());
    }
}
```

The above is an *integration* test, though, not a unit test.